# How to prune nodes in a tree using graph syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, decorations

I want to indicate that nodes have been removed from a tree. Lets say  the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\tikz[tree layout]\graph[nodes={draw, circle}] {        
    a -- {b -- {e -- {k[label=below:1], l[label=below:4]},
    f -- m[label=below:6]},
    c -- g -- {y[label=below:0], z[label=below:2]}, d -- i[label=below:4]} 
};
\end{document}
```

And I want to cut off b to f. How do I do it?

I am using this syntax because this looks familiar to dot language and I am not very antiquated with latex.

P.S. have a look at http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html if you don't know that dot language is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Also, can you add a link which explains what "dot language" is.  BTW, thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), but it didn't compile for me.  I had to use LauLaTeX and got the error message `Unknown key '/tikz/edgel'`